# Why is the unit of a compact closed category coordinate-independent?

Tags: vector-spaces, category-theory

Compact closed categories are equipped with a unit and counit

$$\eta_A: I \to A^* \otimes A$$
$$\varepsilon_A : A^*\otimes A \to I$$

For a particular compact closed category, say **FdVect** it is obvious from the definition that $\varepsilon_A$ is coordinate independent, viz.

$$\varepsilon_A(\alpha,v) = \alpha(v)$$

However, defining the unit by picking an orthonormal basis $\{e_i\}$ for $A$

$$\eta_A(r) = r\sum_i e^*_i \otimes e_i$$

doesn't give something that is obviously coordinate-independent. Is this the right definition for $\eta$, and if so, what makes it coordinate independent?

Comment: It corresponds to ($r$ times) the identity matrix. Isn't that obviously coordinate independent?

Comment: Yes, you're right. I was fixated on the idea that the coordinates of a matrix depend on the choice of basis, forgetting that that's not true for the identity!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Essentially the question has nothing to do with compact-closed categories, but rather with dualizable objects. In some sense, the unit can be dropped from the data of a dualizable object. In fact, it is the unique(!) morphism such that (one of) the triangular identities involving the counit are satisfied. It follows that it has a basis-free characterization. But when you want to write it down in explicit examples with elements, well, you have to use of course that your object is dualizable (since otherwise the unit doesn't exist). So in the case of vector spaces you need to choose a basis in order to say what the unit does on elements. What Zhen Lin has pointed out uses the natural isomorphism $V^* \otimes V \cong \mathrm{End}(V)$, $\phi \otimes v \mapsto \phi(-)v$, but notice that here again the inverse is characterized naturally, but on elements it cannot be written down without choosing a basis of $V$.